# Can I use Recoil without React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, recoiljs

I want to try Recoil for an app that does not use any frameworks, just web components. Redux can be used without frameworks (I suspect Redux Toolkit can too), but all Recoil examples I have seen involve React.

Can I use Recoil without React?

Comment: [Recoil is a state management library for React, so you need to have React installed and running to use Recoil.](https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: That's said, but I accept your answer. No Recoil for me!